# Yield usage in recursive manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, yield

I was playing around with the `yield` and I made up a function that takes 3 numbers and a limit and computes them in a particular way (the computation is not important, but can be seen in the code below).

```
values = []

def compute(limit, a, b, c):
    if a <= limit:
        print("Got {}, {}, {}".format(a, b, c))
        values.append([a, b, c])
        compute(limit, b*c, a*c, a*b)
    else:
        print("Process ended")


compute(9999, 2, 3, 4)
print(values)
```

This works, and produces the output:

```
Got 2, 3, 4
Got 12, 8, 6
Got 48, 72, 96
Got 6912, 4608, 3456
Process ended
[[2, 3, 4], [12, 8, 6], [48, 72, 96], [6912, 4608, 3456]]
```

However, I am sure that this can be done with the usage of `yield` - mainly the `values` list creation part, which, as you see, is filled manually by me in the function.

The reason why I bother at all is just why the `yield` is used in the first place - here it doesn't matter, but what if my task required the 100000th value from this list - constructing it as a whole is not required, or even plainly stupid considering I don't want the previous 99999 values...

I tried using something like:

```
def compute_y(a, b, c):
    while True:
        yield b*c, a*c, b*a

for a, b, c in compute_y(2, 3, 4):
    if a > 9999:
        break
```

The problem with this is that the numbers in the `for` are the same all the time (2, 3 and 4), so it's never gonna reach other values and because of that it's an infinite loop.

tl;dr - can I use yield here at all to make the algorithm more efficient for bigger lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you’ll need to assign the new values for the next loop iteration:

```
def compute_y(a, b, c):
    while True:
        yield a, b, c
        a, b, c = b*c, a*c, b*a
```

Comment: Wait, `yield` doesn't work like `return` in a manner that it just omits the latter and goes straight to the header?

Comment: @Sqoshu: Generators are paused until a value is requested; then they run to the next `yield`. This might help: https://ideone.com/0mPrW5

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the whole problem was caused of me thinking that `yield` works similar to `return` not caring about the latter lines after `yield`.

The whole thing using `yield` (with the hint given by **Ry-**) works like this:

```
def compute_y(a, b, c):
    while True:
        yield a, b, c
        a, b, c = b*c, a*c, b*a


for a, b, c in compute_y(2, 3, 4):
    if a < 9999:
        print(a, b, c)
    else:
        break
```

Output:

```
2 3 4
12 8 6
48 72 96
6912 4608 3456
```